# Flask can't find app file

Tags: python, flask

In [Step 2](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/tutorial/setup/#tutorial-setup) of the official Flask tutorial, Flask cannot find my app file because it's looking in `../venv/Scripts/` instead of where I run the command. How can I tell Flask to look in the right place?

```
(venv) C:\Users\TomV\Codes\flaskr_tutorial>flask run
 * Serving Flask app "flaskr"
 * Forcing debug mode on
 * Restarting with stat
c:\users\tomv\codes\flaskr_tutorial\venv\scripts\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\TomV\Codes\flaskr_tutorial\venv\Scripts\flask': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Stuck on same step. Same error.

Comment: Github issue with a workaround: https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1829

Comment: @AndersE.Andersen Thank you. If you post the workaround here, I'll accept it as answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There seems to a bug according to this github issue:

https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1829

As a workaround you can do

```
>python -m flask run
```

You can also use `>python -m flask initdb` later in the tutorial, when initializing the database (step 4).

Answer (score 5):

You can give full path to app.py when you run "python app.py"

```
python C:/path/to/file/app.py
```

Comment: This worked! But why?

I am on OSX