# Flask-Migrate command 'flask db init' can't find app file

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

Firstly, I'm following the Python Flask tutorial posted here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-crud-web-app-with-python-and-flask-part-one.

Everything was working smoothly up to the 'Migration' section where executing:

```
$ flask db init
```

... failed with the following error:

```
Usage: flask db init [OPTIONS]

Error: The file/path provided (run) does not appear to exist.  Please verify the path is correct.  If app is not on PYTHONPATH, ensure the extension is .py
```

I know the $FLASK_APP env variable is set because this command executes fine:

```
$ flask run
```

Can anyone suggest why this executes fine when running the app, but not when trying to create the migration repository?

The closest I can find elsewhere on the subject is here: [Flask can't find app file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650208/flask-cant-find-app-file), but pre-pending with `python -m` isn't working in either case for me here.

Comment: Are you running the `flask db init` command with your current directory set to the directory that has `run.py`?

Comment: That's right. I'm running all these commands inside the directory that contains run.py.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I had to do

```
python3 -m flask db init
```

Without mentioning python3 -m, it shows

```
zsh: command not found: flask
```

Answer (score 3):

The command `flask run` started the app successfully.

The command `flask db init` failed with the error reported in the question.

So I tried `python run.py` and this failed to start the app by reporting an unmet dependency in `models.py` which was in fact a typo in an import. Fixing the typo and rerunning `python run.py` was successful.

Then I tried `flask run` again, still fine. Then `flask db init`... finally success.

It appears the error reported that it could not find `run.py` is either misleading or masking the true root cause of why it could execute.

Comment: You were correct. Running ```python run.py``` on mine solved the issue after I found a typo. Good looking out

Comment: This helped me as well, the true error gets swallowed when running `flask db init`. In my case I had forgotten to export an environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

In my case my app name was different, and in the directory, I had two flask apps `app.py` and `app_async.py`
And I was also getting the same migrate key error, so this is how I solved it:

```
FLASK_APP=app_async.py flask db init
```

Here I mentioned the app name, and then ran the command.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
pip install flask-migrate --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem occuring,after sometime i noticed that the set FLASK_APP=my_app,but i had a function handling creaion and initializing app so i changed set FLASK_APP=my_app:crate_flask_app,finally it's working for me.
for example:In my_app/**init**.py

```
migrate=Migrate()
db=Sqlalchemy()
defcreate_flask_app():
 app=Flask(__name__)
 db.init_app(app)
 migrate.init_app(app,db)
 return app
```

solution for windows is while declaring FLASK_APP environmental variable if any function is part of creating app then the function should be given after the colon i,e:set FLASK_APP:create_flask_app

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not invoking the command properly. The syntax is, assuming you use a factory function in order to align with the factory pattern:

```
flask --app module_name:factory_fn_name db init.
```

If you are not using the factory pattern, the thing simplifies to:

```
flask --app module_name db init
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using app factory then you should call init_app just as you call that on your db instance.

```
from flask_migrate import Migrate

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    return app
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, but upon closer inspection I had `migrate = Migrate(app)` instead of `migrate = Migrate(app, db)`.