# Flask can't find/run my app even though its in my Pythonpath

Tags: python, flask

I have a very simple Flask app setup locally but when I try to run it I get this error:

```
NoAppException: The file/path provided (cowork_map) does not appear to exist. Please verify the path is correct. If app is not on PYTHONPATH,  ensure the extension is .py
```

Im in a virtual env with flask and all other requirements installed and up to date, I have added the path to my project folder to my $PYTHONPATH and have checked that its there.

I have also used the second answer here to force check if its in my sys.path:

[How to add something to PYTHONPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11960602/how-to-add-something-to-pythonpath)

I have tried force running it with 'python -m flask run' as advised here

[Flask can't find app file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650208/flask-cant-find-app-file)

I ran export 'FLASK_APP=myapp.py' as advised in the official docs.

I have also tried running with with 'FLASK_DEBUG=1' and this is the output:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2017 16:55:13] "GET /? __debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2017 16:55:13] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2017 16:55:13] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2017 16:55:13] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2017 16:55:13] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Mar/2017 16:55:13] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Whats even stranger is that I have another Flask project folder with its own env and that runs just fine, I can't see whats different with this one though.

I should add that everything in my app file is setup correctly with a Flask app initialized.

Also, if I run 'python -mflask run' (with DEBUG on) I get this error on the page when viewed locally:

```
__main__.NoAppException
```

but just 'flask run' displays this:

```
flask.cli.NoAppException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured this out, I have both Python 2.7 and 3 on my machine and there was a module I had imported that was installed on the other version of Python to the one I was using in my env. A very noob error I suppose!